# Challenges with ROC Curve Performance Despite Strong Model Training

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, roc

I would like to create an ROC curve using this code.

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn import metrics
predictions=model.predict_generator(test_datagen,steps=len(test_datagen),verbose=0)
y_pred = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(test_labels,y_pred,pos_label=2)
plt.show()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic for EfficientNetB7')
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, 'b', label = 'AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.show()
```

From the beginning, I have relied on ImageDataGenerator and used fit_generator to train the classification model. The learning curve ,loss curve and Confusion matrix  exhibit overall good performance, as evident from the graphs.
[Learning curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eikIH.png)
[Loss curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNW2K.png)

[confusion matrix image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDRri.png) 
However, there is a challenge concerning the ROC curve, which shows poor performance.
[ROC curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4L0A.png)
Could someone guide me in identifying and correcting the error in the code?

I think the code doesn't correctly handle the multi-class nature of my task. and I tried many codes

I tried to obtain this function
(.predict_proba), but it didn't appear in my model."

Comment: Is the label of your positive class "2"? The `sklearn` code example uses "2" but it might be different in your case, in which case `pos_label=` would be set differently.